# How to use keycloak for sms 2fa authentication?

Tags: authentication, sms, keycloak

I'm trying to use keycloak for sms 2fa authentication.

I tried to use  [this documentation](https://github.com/cooperlyt/keycloak-phone-provider) and used docker to run it and set login theme I can't config a sms service. there is no place to config sms service to send sms to user's phone number.